# Spring Security Remember Me Redirect after RequireFully Authorized

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

All,

I am trying to implement Remember Me functionality

I have two protected urls.

`/operation/fully`  (user must be fully authenticated no remember me allowed)

and

`/operation/authenticated`  (remember me ok)

If I have no remember me cookie and I visit either URL I am prompted for my credentials and redirected to the original URL life is good.

If I am in remember me mode, I can navigate to /operation/authenticated no problem. If I navigate to /operation/fully I am redirected to the login page.  I then authenticate and am taken back to "/"  I want to go back to my original target /operation/fully.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/login">
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
                login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check"  
                authentication-failure-url="/login" />
    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/logout"/>   
    <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/operations/fully" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') and isFullyAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/operations/authenticated" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" />  
    <remember-me key="myKey"
        token-validity-seconds="2419200" />    
 </http>
```

Somehow I need to get the user back to the original requested URL when they aren't fully authenticated. Any ideas on the best approach to do this?

I have come up with one solution, however it makes me cringe as it seems like it is more work than should be necessary.

In my scenario the **ExceptionTranslationFilter** is not invoking the login process and thus is not storing off the original URL.

The following line isn't called

```
    requestCache.saveRequest(request, response);
```

instead a 403 is generated which I was catching via configuration and sending the user to the login page.  In my case the user should be treated as if it they were anonymous and a 403 not be generated and the login process should begin.

The easiest way I found to change this behavior was to change the **AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl**

```
    public boolean isAnonymous(Authentication authentication) {
        if ((anonymousClass == null) || (authentication == null)) {
            return false;
        }

            //if this is a RememberMe me situation, the user should be treated as 
            //if they were anonymous
        if (this.isRememberMe(authentication)){
            return true;
        }

        return anonymousClass.isAssignableFrom(authentication.getClass());
    }
```

This seems to do exactly what I want, however since you can't get access to the **ExceptionTranslationFilter** when using the http namespace I had to do a lot of messy manual configuration.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You didn't make your question clear. Besides, if you want to go back somewhere, then you must include that information somewhere. So when you redirect your user to the login page, you gotta also send information which points back to the original page, so that once the user logs in, you can take him back to where he was.

Comment: I don't know how exactly to make it clearer,  when authorization fails due to my not being fully authenticated I am redirected to the login page, I know I need to include the page that I intend to go to somehow but I am not sure how and where to capture it.  I am looking into grabbing into in **AccessDeniedHandlerImpl** where I have access to it, but I am unsure where exactly to stow it away for later use.

Comment: Your post has no question marks. That would be a good first step into making it clearer - ensure people can immediately recognize *what you are asking*, as it will bring you better luck in getting answered.

Comment: Mention *which* version of Spring Security you are using.

Comment: Your solution would also break proper anonymous detection, so I would consider it a hack. The best would be to patch the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and add a check for when `!isFullyAuthenticated` instead of anonymous. That would redirect you to the same place but it would be fixed in a better place.

Comment: That is also proposed with an (long standing) open issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2427.

Comment: Since the user who asked this question seems to have left SO, let's assume Spring Security 4.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/3832) scheduled for Spring Security 4.2.0 M1 to address this need. Its associated commit probably gives hints to implement the same thing in previous versions of Spring Security.